# Python 3 How to get string between two points using regex?

Tags: regex, string, parsing, python-3.x

How to get the string between two points using regex or any other library in Python 3?

For eg:
Blah blah ABC the string to be retrieved XYZ Blah Blah

ABC and XYZ are variables which denote the start and end of the string which I have to retrieve.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `ABC` and `XYZ` as anchors with look-behind and look-ahead assertions:

```
(?<=ABC).*?(?=XYZ)
```

The `(?<=...)` look-behind assertion only matches at the location in the text that was preceded by `ABC`. Similarly, `(?=XYZ)` matches at the location that is followed by `XYZ`. Together they form two anchors that limit the `.*` expression, which matches anything.

You can find all such anchored pieces of text with `re.findall()`:

```
for matchedtext in re.findall(r'(?<=ABC).*?(?=XYZ)', inputtext):
```

If `ABC` and `XYZ` are variable, you want to use `re.escape()` (to prevent any of their content from being interpreted as regular expression syntax) on them and interpolate:

```
re.match(r'(?<={}).*?(?={})'.format(abc, xyz), inputtext)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you want:

```
import re
match = re.search('ABC(.*)XYZ','Blah blah ABC the string to be retrieved XYZ Blah Blah')
print match.group(1)
```

Comment: good way, but add a question mark after the * quantifier to make it lazy if you don't want to match something like `ABC( ... XYZ ... )XYZ`

Comment: @user1572508 ABC and XYZ are variables to be taken from the user

Comment: What if I just want the content in '(.*)' ?