# How to capture multiple substrings between two markers using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I know how to capture a single instance of a substring between two markers:

[Python 3 How to get string between two points using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151405/python-3-how-to-get-string-between-two-points-using-regex)

I tested that approach out with this string:

```
text = 'blah.blah${capture1}.${capture2}'
```

I wanted to get all the substrings between these markers '${' and '}', but it only gets the first one.

```
>>> text = 'blah.blah${capture1}.${capture2}'
>>> found = re.search('\$\{(.+?)\}', text)
>>> found.groups()
('capture1',)
>>> len(found.groups())
1
>>>
```

How do I get all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regex method that will find all the matches in a string. You should try `re.findall('\$\{(.+?)\}', text)` or `re.finditer('\$\{(.+?)\}', text)`. The first will return a list, the second will return an iterable.