# Extract all matching substrings between two characters in the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column containing html.

I'm trying to extract everything between the list tags, (<li> and </li>) and return in a new column named 'output'.

I'd like to include the <li> and </li> tags too as part of the output.

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': ['1', '2'],
    'Description': ['blah blah <li>Point 1</li>blah blah<li>Point 2</li>blah blah blah', 'blah<li>Point1</li>blah<li>Point 2</li>']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new'] = df.Description.apply(lambda st: st[st.find("<li>")+1:st.find("</li>")])
print(df)
```

**Desired Output**

```
  ID                                        Description         output
0  1  blah blah <li>Point 1</li>blah blah<li>Point 2...  <li>Point 1</l><li>Point 2</li>
1  2            blah<li>Point1</li>blah<li>Point 2</li>  <li>Point 1</l><li>Point 2</li>
```

What I've tried:
Although there appears to be a lot of solutions around ('extracting substrings between two strings') there isn't anything that comes close.

For example, this (and many other result) only return the first instance
[Extract substring between two characters in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660357/extract-substring-between-two-characters-in-pandas) but I need to extract all instances.

Also I haven't seen any that will preserve the <li> tags.

Comment: Depending on the variability of your inputs you may want to look in to an HTML parser and iterate through each record. If there are a non-variable number of `<li>` tags you could use a regex like this https://regex101.com/r/0gyxMk/1

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. It looks like I've got some reading to do! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look-behind assertion and look-ahead assertion to get your desired result. You can look into this amazing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17151522/16836078) to understand more.

In your case, `(?=<li>)` will match the string followed by `<li>` while `(?<=</li>)` will match the string preceded by `</li>`.

```
result = df.Description.str.findall(r'(?=<li>).*?(?<=</li>)')

0    [<li>Point 1</li>, <li>Point 2</li>]
1     [<li>Point1</li>, <li>Point 2</li>]
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Eventually, you assign it back to the dataframe.

```
df['output'] = result
```